# No prop for export button in DataGrid

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

[image]
I wanted to disable or remove the export button but there were no props in the documentation to disable this button.

```
  <DataGrid
        rows={suppliers}
        columns={columns}
        getRowId={(row) => row.supplier_id}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        // disableColumnFilter
        // disableColumnSelector
        // disableDensitySelector
        components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
        componentsProps={{
            toolbar: {
                showQuickFilter: true,
                quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 500 }
            }
        }}
    />
```

Example:

```
disableColumnFilter
disableColumnSelector
disableDensitySelector
```

Comment: If that export is an MUI button, then you just need to add the prop disabled, you can check it out right here: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/

Comment: How could I do that? I just called the GridToolbar component to show the quick filter field.

Comment: Well I think this is a duplicate question, found the possible answer on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484751/mui-xgrid-disabling-export-button-from-gridtoolbar